# App settings appear in simulator but wont on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, jailbreak, cydia

I use Xcode 6.1.1 and iOS 8.1 swift. Simulator is have app settings in settings. But real device not. I use Local notifications & background fetch. No warning & errors. I have not apple developer account.

I sign with ldid to build my jailbreak iphone. App working but not showing notifications and background data settings in iphone settings.app.

Is This jailbreak issue or ldid?

Here is some news. I build other tutorial projects for notifications. Same thing happened. I think not code issue. Because first build is crash on device. If i build again no crash on device but app not ask allow notification question. And app settings not appear. But app is working without background fetch & notification.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for app settings to show up a proper Apple-signed app ID is required. Pay the $99 and get your code properly signed, or you may need to use some Settings plugin mechanism for jailbreak tweaks.

Comment: I think same as you. But i wanna know how to make without pay 99. I am not a professional developer, and i havent app to put store. So i dont want buy dev acc. If anyone know how make this with tweak mechanism i am very grateful for this.

Comment: I am not part of this jailbreak tweak development scene but there are frameworks for this purpose. Google around and you will see.